# How to implement "SKAdNetwork" and app tracking in iOS app with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tracking, skadnetwork

Since iOS 14 app tracking is introduced. I need help in SKAdNetwork implementation. as it is a new concept i didn't find any proper tutorial or documentation.

I just got one Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/

from here what i understood is we can implement skadnetwork in two ways

**1)Source apps:** ad networks shows ad in our app

**2)Advertised apps:** our app will be shown as ad in other apps to download

**now my question is how to configure our app in these ways and how to implement their methods** i didn't get any codes for method implementation. please guide me this concept.

Comment: `SKAddNetwork` does not deliver adds. You need to chose an advertising provider that supports `SKAdNetwork` and then follow the implementation guide from that provider.

Comment: @Paulw11, okay for 2nd approach also do we need `advertising provider`?.  i need to show my app as an ad in other published apps. is there any steps with code implementation in methods.

Comment: Yes, you need an advertising provider for the second part too; you need to pay the ad provider to show your ads on their network.

Comment: @Paulw11, how can i reach to `advertising provider` that supports SKAdNetwork ? to show my app as an ad of others apps. do i get advertising provider that supports SKAdNetwork through  `Registering an ad network in Apple developer account` ?.. please share info.. i didn't get proper reference from anywhere.

Comment: Type "skadnetwork" into Google?  Most providers will support it. Eg https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14